# Are webservices exposed to any one?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

I'm very new to web services (please note, not WCF but the old fashioned .asmx files).

Now I may be liking this too much to ports, but if I expose a port on my web facing server then it is exposed to attacks as well as my own use; There are tools which can scan to see what ports are open.

Is this true of a web service? Now, don't get me wrong, I know each service should be coded well enough that nothing malicious can happen or that the calling class doesn't know the 'contract' to implement them, but that's not the question (and I guess port flooding could still occur?); If I put up a few web services on a server, is there a tool/program which can detect them (by name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a web service is basically a web page that takes arguments and response with a formatted result that can be read more easily by a program (technically both are a result of a http request and response - there are other mechanisms as well, but the typical one is over the http protocol).

If you type the link to your web service in a browser you will see you are presented with an interface that allows you to "execute" its services.

Therefor you need the same security as with a web page, meaning login or check of credentials, tokens, signing, encryption and so forth (preferably on a ssl-connection).

Comment: and as such, naming the service/page WebServicesWhichUsesWseSecurity would therefore be un-desireable I assume as people will see what security is used (I know a silly point)!

Comment: In my opinion it wouldn't matter so much what you call it. The most important is to make it "hacker proof" (if such thing exist) so it can be exposed by anyone without serving a risk.

Comment: I didn't find it silly, it's a legitimate question and since webservices are most of the time "invisible" compared to an ordinary web page I can understand why anyone would ask.

Comment: You may look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security for one or other form of security.